# Basic question on numerical precision

Tags: floating-point

I appreciate this opportunity to submit a query on this forum.

When studying the continuous-time & discrete-time distinction, specifically with reference to discrete signals being identical when separated by 2*pi, it has struck me that a basic premise, per google calc, doesn't hold:

- exp(**2** * pi * sqrt(-1)) = 1
- exp(**4** * pi * sqrt(-1)) = 1
- exp(**6** * pi * sqrt(-1)) = 1
- exp(**8** * pi * sqrt(-1)) = 1

but...

- exp(**10** * pi * sqrt(-1)) = 1 - 1.2246468 × 10^-15 i

Any thoughts on the above (discrepancy?) would be appreciated.

Regards,

```
wirefree
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with discrete signals but with the computer representation of numbers.

Comment: `pi` does not equal $\pi$ exactly; it is an approximation (correct to $7$ or $8$ decimal places) to $\pi$

Comment: If you use a program capable of symbolic (not just numeric) computation, you'll get the exact result. [Example using Wolfram Alpha.](https://imgur.com/jOJPaT3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing another way

$$1 - 1.2246468 × 10^{-15} i = 1 - 0.0000000000000012246468i$$

It is just rounding errors adding up due to having a limited number of bits in whatever computer is doing the calculation.